# How to move the url date to the end of the reference?

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}

\bibliography{references}
\printbibliography[title={References}]
```

The reference entry:

```
@electronic{reference,
title           = {something},
url             = {https://google.com},
month           = Nov,
year            = {2016}
}
```

The reference appears as:

[1] (Nov. 2016) something, [online]. Available: https://google.com

I want it to appear as:

[1] something, [online]. Available: https://google.com (last visited Nov. 2016)

Comment: You'll want to give the date in `urldate` and not  the`year` and `month` fields: `urldate = {2016-11}`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to give the date of access of your URL reference, you need to use the `urldate` field. `date` (and `year`, `month`) are for the actual date of publishing (or equivalent) of the source.

So you want

```
@online{reference,
  title   = {something},
  url     = {https://example.edu/~elk/something},
  urldate = {2016-11},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get "last visited" in parentheses after the url, the following works for me.

1. Add `url=FALSE` to the package options (this prevents the url from being printed twice)
2. Define the `bibstring` for `urlseen`
3. Declare the field format for `urldate` as url then parentheses then `urlseen`

See below:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    natbib=true,
    citestyle=authordate,
    style=chicago-authordate, 
    backref=false, 
    autocite=inline, 
    sortcites=true, 
    url=false, 
    urldate=long, 
    isbn=false, 
    doi=false,
    sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {last visited},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\printfield{url} \mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can format code by clicking the `{}` button or by indenting it with four spaces. You can write lists with `1.` etc instead of `1)`.

Comment: Note that your `\usepackage{biblatex}` is a bit unconventional. If you want to use `biblatex-chicago` you should load the style using the wrapper package `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` and not with `biblatex` itself. `style=...` should also overwrite a previous `citestyle=...`, so `citestyle=authordate,` is useless. There are exceptions, but usually I would consider `\printfield` within a `\DeclareFieldFormat` as bas form. On the other hand one should prefer `\addspace` or `\space` instead of a literal space in `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

Comment: For the standard styles the more idiomatic solution would be to modify the bibmacro `url+urldate`. For `biblatex-chicago` I would also prefer to modify the responsible macro (`bib+doi+url`) and the `@online` driver (ugh!), but I admit that that would be more painful here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I will format my answers properly in the future. Biblatex-chicago doesn't work so well for me. I did try to modify the bib macro, but it didn't work. Thanks for the other suggestions, good to know.